# Win32 equivalent of opendir

Tags: winapi, file, directory, io

Would anyone know what the Win32 equivalent of opendir is (or if it even exists) ?
Obviously I could use FindFirstFile(Ex) with FindNextFile, but appending * to the path seems like such a hackish way to do it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about this approach seems "hackish" to you?  Your answer might help us come up with an appropriate response...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` are the appropriate Win32 APIs. Assuming you're writing C++ code, as a portable alternative you could consider using `directory_iterator` from the [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library (which is implemented on Windows using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) with `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` and then [`BackupRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362509(VS.85).aspx) to read directory data, but I'm not sure what format the data is actually in. Also, you would need to be running as a user with the `SE_BACKUP_NAME` privilege enabled, so this is not really suitable in a general purpose application.